# Debugging Python, stay in current stack trace (not cycle after each command)

Tags: python, pdb

Say I am debugging some python code, for interest sake it's a Django application, that has a `breakpoint()` in it, while stepping the code, another request may come and hit the same breakpoint. Now there are multiple concurrent debugger instances. And sometimes its more than 2.

With after eacvh debugger command it cycles to the next debugging instance.

So say one says `x=1`. Then you say `pp x`, x will be undefined because it switched to another debugging session. It makes debugging pretty impossible how it cycles through unknown to me number of instances.

How do I make the debugger never switch from the current debugging session, but to wait until its done (e.g. via 'continue')?

Comment: Rather than including small bits of code in your description, it would be more useful to those that may want to help you to describe your problem in full, including what you've attempted to solve the problem, followed by the code itself.

Comment: Hi @Beatdown, I described the problem as well as I got, the code base is 160K lines of code. And it is general debugging, not linked to any exact piece of code in particular.